# Formulário em angular dado não chegar na api

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma aplicação em Angular/TypeScript no frontend, no qual esta consumindo as informações de uma Web Api, backend que foi feita em Asp.Net Core, esta normal. A minha duvida é tenho um formulário em Html, no qual tem alguns cálculos que realizo em javascript, no "client", porem no momento que envio o formulário para a WebApi, o campo que "null".

Se o usuário digita o valor, o dado chega na Api. Porem se eu faço o calculo pejo javascript, não chega o valor.

Setei as diretiva ng untouched para ng touched e ng pristine para ng dirty no html, porem o problema persiste.

Alguem poderia orientar que posso fazer ?

Att

Html

```
                            <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="produto.id" id="produto.id" name="produto.id" #produto.id="ngModel">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Nome</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.nome" id="produto.nome" name="produto.nome" #produto.nome="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Quantidade</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.quantidade" id="produto.quantidade" name="produto.quantidade" #produto.quantidade="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Quantidade minina</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.quantidademinima" id="produto.quantidademinima" name="produto.quantidademinina" #produto.quantidademinina="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Valor</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.valor" id="produto.valor" name="produto.valor" #produto.valor="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Valor custo unitário</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.valorcustounitario" id="produto.valorcustounitario" name="produto.valorcustounitario" #produto.valorcustounitario="ngModel" onblur="CalcularProduto()">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field id="matvalorcustototal" class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Valor custo total</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.valorcustototal" id="produto.valorcustototal" name="produto.valorcustototal" #produto.valorcustototal="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Valor lucro unitário</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.valorlucrounitario" id="produto.valorlucrounitario" name="produto.valorlucrounitario" #produto.valorlucrounitario="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Valor lucro total</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.valorlucrototal" id="produto.valorlucrototal" name="produto.valorlucrototal" #produto.valorLucroTotal="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Valor bruto</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.valorbruto" id="produto.valorbruto" name="produto.valorbruto" #produto.valorbruto="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <mat-label>Categoria</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="produto.idcategoria" id="produto.idcategoria" name="produto.idcategoria" #produto.idcategoria="ngModel">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add-produto">Salvar</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-add-protudo" (click)="cleanForm(f)">Cancelar</button>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function CalcularProduto() {
    var quantidade = document.getElementById("produto.quantidade");
    console.log(quantidade);
    var valor = document.getElementById("produto.valor");
    console.log(valor);
    var custo = document.getElementById("produto.valorCustoUnitario");
    console.log(custo);
    var totalCusto = custo.value * quantidade.value;
    console.log(totalCusto);
    document.getElementById("produto.valorCustoTotal").value = totalCusto.toFixed(2);
    var lucroUnitario = valor.value - custo.value;
    document.getElementById("produto.valorLucroUnitario").value = lucroUnitario.toFixed(2);
    var lucroTotal = lucroUnitario * quantidade.value;
    document.getElementById("produto.valorLucroTotal").value = lucroTotal.toFixed(2);
    var bruto = lucroTotal + totalCusto;
    document.getElementById("produto.valorBruto").value = bruto.toFixed(2);
};
function moeda(a, e, r, t) {
let n = ""
  , h = j = 0
  , u = tamanho2 = 0
  , l = ajd2 = ""
  , o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
if (13 == o || 8 == o)
    return !0;
if (n = String.fromCharCode(o),
-1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
    return !1;
for (u = a.value.length,
h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++)
    ;
for (l = ""; h < u; h++)
    -1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
if (l += n,
0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""),
1 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + "0" + l),
2 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + l),
u > 2) {
    for (ajd2 = "",
    j = 0,
    h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
        3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
        j = 0),
        ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
        j++;
    for (a.value = "",
    tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
    h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
        a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
    a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
}
return !1
}
```

Solução

Javascript

```
function CalcularProduto() {
        var quantidade = document.getElementById("produto.quantidade");
        var valor = document.getElementById("produto.valor");
        var custo = document.getElementById("produto.valorcustounitario");
        var totalCusto = custo.value * quantidade.value;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorcustototal").value = totalCusto;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorcustototal").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", totalCusto);
        var lucroUnitario = valor.value - custo.value;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrounitario").value = lucroUnitario
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrounitario").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", lucroUnitario);
        var lucroTotal = lucroUnitario * quantidade.value;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrototal").value = lucroTotal
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrototal").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", lucroTotal);
        var bruto = lucroTotal + totalCusto;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorbruto").value = bruto
        document.getElementById("produto.valorbruto").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", bruto);
  };
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProdutoService } from '../service/produto.service';
import { Produto } from '../models/produto.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-produto',
  templateUrl: '../component/produto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../component/produto.component.scss']
})

export class ProdutoComponent implements OnInit {

  produtos: Produto[];
  produto = {} as Produto;

  constructor(private produtoService: ProdutoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProdutos();
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    console.log(this.produto);
  }

  //Selecionar todos os produtos
  public getProdutos() {
    return this.produtoService.getProdutos().subscribe(
                  produtos => { this.produtos = produtos; }, 
                  err => { console.log('Erro ao listar produtos', err);}
                )
  };

  //Deletar um produto
  public deleteProduto(produto: Produto) {
    this.produtoService.deleteProduto(produto).subscribe(() => {
      this.getProdutos();
    });
  }

  //Adicionar produto
  public addProduto(form: NgForm) {
    let pvct = document.getElementById("produto.valorcustototal").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    let pvlu = document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrounitario").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    let pvlt = document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrototal").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    let pvb = document.getElementById("produto.valorbruto").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    this.produto.valorcustototal = pvct;
    this.produto.valorlucrounitario = pvlu;
    this.produto.valorlucrototal = pvlt;
    this.produto.valorbruto = pvb;
    if (this.produto.id !== undefined) {
        this.produtoService.updateProduto(this.produto).subscribe(() => {
          this.cleanForm(form);
          window.location.reload();
        });
      } else {
        this.produtoService.addProduto(this.produto).subscribe(() => {
          this.cleanForm(form);
          window.location.reload();
        });
      }
    }

  //Limpar formulário de produto
  public cleanForm(form: NgForm) {
    this.getProdutos();
    form.resetForm();
  }

  //Editar produto
  editProduto(produto: Produto) {
    this.produto = { ...produto };
  }

}
```

Setei o atributo reflect-model no HTML, e no TypeScript passo o valor para o obj THIS.

Comment: Mas se está utilizando **Angular** pq a função está em **Vanilla**?

Comment: Pq estou fazendo o calculo sem request, tipo o usuário vai digitar o valor e quantidade, quando sair do campo "blur()" ele faz o calculo

Comment: Rodrigo ou eu não entendi a pergunta ou ela está sem nexo algum. Se a função está em Vanilla e é executada no evento **onblur** como pretende que o seu model sejá preenchido pelos valores da função?

Comment: Então, a função preenche o "value" do elemento HTML, porem quando eu dou o SUBMIT do formulário, no MODEL não pega o valor, fica em estado indefinido este atributo. Sai da aplicação angular INDEFINIDO e no backend, chega NULL.

Não sei se fui claro. Podemos fazer um call?

Att

Rodrigo

Comment: Você está tentando fazer de uma forma totalmente anti-padrão Angular, te recomendo a ler: https://angular.io/guide/forms#introduction-to-template-driven-forms

Comment: Vou ver aqui, obrigado.

Comment: Consegui amigo.

Comment: @RodrigoFurlaneti se conseguiu, compartilhe sua resposta e marque-a como **solução**, para visitantes futuros verem que a sua pergunta foi solucionada.

Answer (score 0):

Solução

Javascript

```
function CalcularProduto() {
        var quantidade = document.getElementById("produto.quantidade");
        var valor = document.getElementById("produto.valor");
        var custo = document.getElementById("produto.valorcustounitario");
        var totalCusto = custo.value * quantidade.value;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorcustototal").value = totalCusto;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorcustototal").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", totalCusto);
        var lucroUnitario = valor.value - custo.value;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrounitario").value = lucroUnitario
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrounitario").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", lucroUnitario);
        var lucroTotal = lucroUnitario * quantidade.value;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrototal").value = lucroTotal
        document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrototal").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", lucroTotal);
        var bruto = lucroTotal + totalCusto;
        document.getElementById("produto.valorbruto").value = bruto
        document.getElementById("produto.valorbruto").setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", bruto);
  };
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProdutoService } from '../service/produto.service';
import { Produto } from '../models/produto.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-produto',
  templateUrl: '../component/produto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../component/produto.component.scss']
})

export class ProdutoComponent implements OnInit {

  produtos: Produto[];
  produto = {} as Produto;

  constructor(private produtoService: ProdutoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProdutos();
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    console.log(this.produto);
  }

  //Selecionar todos os produtos
  public getProdutos() {
    return this.produtoService.getProdutos().subscribe(
                  produtos => { this.produtos = produtos; }, 
                  err => { console.log('Erro ao listar produtos', err);}
                )
  };

  //Deletar um produto
  public deleteProduto(produto: Produto) {
    this.produtoService.deleteProduto(produto).subscribe(() => {
      this.getProdutos();
    });
  }

  //Adicionar produto
  public addProduto(form: NgForm) {
    let pvct = document.getElementById("produto.valorcustototal").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    let pvlu = document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrounitario").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    let pvlt = document.getElementById("produto.valorlucrototal").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    let pvb = document.getElementById("produto.valorbruto").getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");
    this.produto.valorcustototal = pvct;
    this.produto.valorlucrounitario = pvlu;
    this.produto.valorlucrototal = pvlt;
    this.produto.valorbruto = pvb;
    if (this.produto.id !== undefined) {
        this.produtoService.updateProduto(this.produto).subscribe(() => {
          this.cleanForm(form);
          window.location.reload();
        });
      } else {
        this.produtoService.addProduto(this.produto).subscribe(() => {
          this.cleanForm(form);
          window.location.reload();
        });
      }
    }

  //Limpar formulário de produto
  public cleanForm(form: NgForm) {
    this.getProdutos();
    form.resetForm();
  }

  //Editar produto
  editProduto(produto: Produto) {
    this.produto = { ...produto };
  }

}
```

Setei o atributo reflect-model no HTML, e no TypeScript passo o valor para o obj THIS.